# postgresql WHERE IN (list) multiple tables return data from table 2

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following will return 2 records as expected.

```
SELECT 
    cds_Prod.ProdID, 
    catid, 
    imgid, 
    mfid, 
    mfpn
FROM 
    public.cds_prod
WHERE
    cds_Prod.mfpn IN ('726722-B21', 'SUP-UFMSDN-4K-1GP')
LIMIT 
    1000
```

Now I need to combine the a description for each result... This is my attempt

```
SELECT 
    cds_Prod.ProdID, 
    catid, 
    imgid, 
    mfid, 
    mfpn, 
    cds_Stdnez.Description 
FROM 
    public.cds_prod, 
    public.cds_stdnez
WHERE
    cds_Prod.mfpn IN ('726722-B21', 'SUP-UFMSDN-4K-1GP')
LIMIT 
    1000
```

That returns over 1000 records that have the same `mfpn`. What i really want is the first 2 records but with descriptions attached.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @chimchimz I am new at sql. I am using the SQL you see above. Nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the join key.

```
   SELECT 
    cds_Prod.ProdID, 
    catid, 
    imgid, 
    mfid, 
    mfpn, 
    cds_Stdnez.Description 
FROM 
    public.cds_prod a 
    LEFT JOIN public.cds_stdnez b on a.ProdID = b.ProdID
WHERE
    cds_Prod.mfpn IN ('726722-B21', 'SUP-UFMSDN-4K-1GP')
LIMIT 
    1000
```

Comment: @Omar is there a reason that you accepted the latest answer?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is an old fashioned join but you are missing the link between the 2 tables.
There has to be a column in the table `cds_stdnez` that references the column `ProdID` of the table `cds_Prod`, with a similar name like `ProdID`, so add an ON clause:

```
FROM public.cds_prod INNER JOIN public.cds_stdnez
ON cds_Prod.ProdID = cds_stdnez.ProdID
```

and even better use aliases for the tables and qualify all the columns with these aliases:

```
SELECT 
    p.ProdID, 
    p.catid, 
    p.imgid, 
    p.mfid, 
    p.mfpn, 
    s.Description 
FROM 
    public.cds_prod AS p INNER JOIN public.cds_stdnez AS s
    ON p.ProdID = s.ProdID
WHERE
    p.mfpn IN ('726722-B21', 'SUP-UFMSDN-4K-1GP')
LIMIT 
    1000
```

Note that `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is never a good idea.